# How do i get the MongoDB version number on Heroku?

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I am not sure how to get the MongoDB version number that is running on Heroku?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Connect to the mongo database using the mongo client and run

```
> db.version()
```

This will print out the current running version.

You will need to supply hostname/username/password to mongo using:

```
 mongo -h hostname:port_number -d database_name -u username -p password
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about MongoHQ on Heroku, you can see that from the MongoHQ add-on dashboard under "Database Info".

On mine it shows up like this, in the "Server Status" section:
[image]

This way, you can avoid installing the mongo client locally. Although, that is probably recommended, for other uses.

Comment: I actually dont see this under Database Info...?

Comment: Oh well, I guess Heroku doesn't display all of the MongoHQ details, or maybe it depends on the size of database.