# Error: can't find any special indices 2d (needs index) 2dsphere (needs index)

Tags: mongodb, heroku

When i use this find command on heroku cloud server:

```
users.find({$and: [
{loc: { $nearSphere: user.loc.coordinates,
        $maxDistance: user.dis / 3959}},
{age: {$gte: user.age_down}},
{age: {$lte: user.age_up}},
{gender: user.interested},
{interested: user.gender}]})
```

i get the `can't find any special indices 2d (needs index) 2dsphere (needs index)` Error.

the results (in heroku) of the db.users.getIndexes() are:

```
PRIMARY> db.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "app27206755.users",
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "loc" : "2dsphere"
                },
                "ns" : "app27206755.users",
                "name" : "loc_2dsphere",
                "background" : true
        }
]
```

the weird thing is that in my local server it works perfectly (the same code exactly) but the problem is only on heroku.. i think that maybe i have a newer version of mongo on my local machin. the problem is that i dont know how to update the version of mongodb on the heroku cloud server, or if its even possible?

***Update***: i just found that the version of mongo in heroku is 2.4.8 and in my local machine is 2.6.3.
any idea how to upgrade ?

thanks !

Comment: The versions you've listed are your node's *bindings* to mongodb, not the mongodb server itself. I don't think that's the error in this case however. What's the output of `db.users.getIndexes()` in the mongo shell (on Heroku)? I think you forgot to run `ensureIndex`.

Comment: ensureIndex needs to be run separately from the code ? see updated post.. thanks !

Comment: Seems like your indexes are fine. I found [this old bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4572) which might be responsible. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546794/how-do-i-get-the-mongodb-version-number-on-heroku) for how to determine your mongodb version. I don't know enough about Heroku to be able to tell you how to update your mongodb installation, though.

Comment: I found that the current version of the mongodb is 2.4.8

Comment: You might want to ask how to update MongoDB version on Heroku as a separate question and mark this as closed, as it seems to be a known issue (fixed as of 2.5.5).